# How to debug the fact that StartCoroutine wont start the coroutine with no error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, coroutine, unitywebrequest

The Class Gettext starts a Unitywebrewuest to google.com but after the console pints "index1" nothing happens and no error are displayed. How could I solve / debug this ( in Visual Studio I can't start the debugger).

Thank you a lot for the time!

```
public class Gettext : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    private string m_fileContentWebGl = "aaa";
    public Gettext()
    {
        callGettext(m_fileContent => {
        });
    }


    public void callGettext(Action<string> onTextResult)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("stage1");
        StartCoroutine(this.GetText(onTextResult));
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("stage3");
    }

    public IEnumerator GetText(Action<string> onResult)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("here");
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://google.com");
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its pretty odd that you are using a constructor for a monobehaviour derived class. You're not supposed to use them, that may be affecting the coroutine, I dunno.

Try changing

```
public Gettext()
    {
        callGettext(m_fileContent => {
        });
    }
```

to

```
void Start
    {
        callGettext(m_fileContent => {
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Grizzly.... unfortunately it makes no change... please let me know if you have any other ideas...or at least how I could debug

Comment: is that GetText component on a gameobject in the scene?

Comment: It needs to be on a gameobject in the scene. Otherwise the coroutine will not run, coroutine runs on update more or less.